# this.component.name TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple nav link, so what I want to do is if some state matches it's name I will set that as active but currently I can't do so. Currently I'm doing this `active={this.state.navState==='login'}` and so on.

```
<Nav variant="tabs">
  <Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Link
      active={this.state.navState === 'login'}
      name="login"
      onClick={this.changeType}>
      Login
    </Nav.Link>
  </Nav.Item>
  <Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Link
      active={this.state.navState === 'signin'}
      name="signin"
      onClick={this.changeType}>
      Signup
    </Nav.Link>
  </Nav.Item>
</Nav>
```

I have also tried:

- `this.component.name`
- `this.target.tagName`
- `this.props.name`

but it gives me error saying **TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

I want to read `<Nav.Link active={this.state.navState==='signin'} **name**="signin"`, the **name** marked

Comment: can post the whole component please?

Comment: you can start debugging with `this.state.navState`, it would be better if you can create working demo.

Comment: my navState is set to 'login', so first one should be active, the problem is how can I get the element name

Comment: this is react-bootstrap, right? According to the docs the `activeKey` prop on the `Nav` component marks the child `Nav.Link` components as active. I don't see a `name` prop being supported.

Comment: Can you update your question with the `changeType` function as well. The error might be inside this fucntion

Comment: Can you post the code for function changeType here? @Danial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you changeType use like this :

```
changeType = (e) =>{    
    const el = e.target;
    console.log(el.getAttribute("name"));
  }
```

simple demo : [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactroutercss-011xf)